# HKDF and key stretching

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash, key-generation

I thought that all key derivation functions would do a key stretching phase, by iterating some kind of process. But I can't see that process in HKDF. HKDF doesn't do key strengthening?

If I have a passphrase as input, and I need, let's say, 1024bytes derived from this passphrase (some bytes for encryption, some bytes for a MAC). What would you recommend? Going directly for PBKDF2? Or using HKDF in some way?

Answer (score 18):

[HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) is a [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function): it turns a symmetric key (a bunch of bytes) into another symmetric key, which can be longer (that's the point of the exercise).

Doing multiple inner iterations, to make the function *slow*, is a defence mechanism which makes sense when the input key is of inherently low entropy -- e.g. when it is a **password** (that's an unavoidable biological fact: as a storage medium for random-looking data, human brains suck). Deriving a key *from a password* is a task which is more complex than simply deriving a key from another key. HKDF does not pretend to handle the "password" bit. For that you need [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), which is password-based (that's the "PB" part) and also uses HMAC, this time with a configurable (and potentially huge) number of iterations.

HKDF is a building block for some cryptographic protocols, not something to use directly.

Comment: Nicely put! Honestly, I think you should also brush up some of the wikipedia articles. It would serve a lot of students (and non-students) when they're trying to read up on stuff.