# Is there a security risk using a Symmetric-key for both encryption and HMACing

Tags: aes, risk

I am proposing to use an AES key to encrypt some data to send to a third party and in a completely separate operation/flow use the same key to create a HMAC of a message to send to the same third party.

I have been told that this is a risk to use the same key for two different things.  I cannot find any information on why this is a risk.  If this is a risk, what is it?

I have found information on this site explaining why you should use different RSA keys pairs for encryption and signing and that makes sense, but nothing on symmetric keys.

[Why should one not use the same asymmetric key for encryption as they do for signing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *"by the book"* approach to this is to use a [key-stretching/key-derivation-function](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38303/hkdf-and-key-stretching) to turn a one secret into another (longer) secret. Or two or more secrets. One for HMAC, one AES session key, etc.

This [is what TLS does](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99537/mastersecret-expansion-into-keys/99573#99573). It expands the master secret into a block of six single other secrets.

I can not name a practical attack if you don't do that.

But stretching the key is cheap. And afterwards you don't have to worry about related primitives attacks anymore. If nothing else, it's a method that allows you to mentally compartmentalize the different crypto parts. It makes the whole construction a lot easier to talk about.